# I have a small problem understanding how objects choose what methods to take when there's inheritance

Tags: java, oop, object

Doing some homework and found out a small problem i cant understand
Basically second line of **C** and **D** are A.f(double=...) and i dont understand why they did not use the functions from C and D can anybody explain how it works?

```
class A {
    void f(double x ) { 
        System.out.print ("A.f(double=" + x + ") "); 
    }
}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {
    void f(long q ) {
        System.out.print ("C.f(long=" + q + ") ");
    }
}
class D extends C {
    void f(int n) { 
         System.out.print ("D.f(int=" + n + ") "); 
    }
}
class E extends B {}
class F extends C { 
    void f(float x ) { 
        System.out.print ("F.f(float=" + x + ") ");
     }
    void f(int n ) {
        System.out.print("F.f(int=" + n + ") "); 
    }
}
public class PolySur {
    public static void main (String args [ ]) {
        byte bb=1 ; short p =2; int n=3; 
        long q=4; float x=5.f; double y=6;
        System.out.println ("** A **");
        A a = new A() ; 
        a.f(bb) ; 
        a.f(x); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ("** B **");
        B b = new B( ) ; b.f(bb) ; b.f(x); 
        System.out.println();
        a = b;
        a.f(bb) ; 
        a.f(x); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ("** C **");
        C c = new C( ) ; c.f(bb) ; c.f(q); 
        c.f(x); 
        System.out.println();
        a = c; 
        a.f(bb) ; 
        a.f(q); 
        a.f(x); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ("** D **");
        D d = new D(); 
        d.f(bb) ;
        d.f(q); 
        d.f(y);
        System.out.println();
        a = c; 
        a.f(bb) ;
         a.f(q); 
         a.f(y); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ("** F **");
        F f = new F();
        f.f(bb) ;
        f.f(n); 
        f.f(x); 
        f.f(y); 
        f.f(p); 
        System.out.println();
        a = f; 
        a.f(bb) ; 
        a.f(n);
        a.f(q); 
        a.f(x); 
        a.f(y); 
        System.out.println();
        c = f; 
        c.f(bb) ; 
        c.f(n); 
        c.f(x); 
        c.f(y); 
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: there is no indentation in the code, its not readable.

Comment: Sorry im on phone and didnt factor this thanks for the edit

Comment: I just edited your question on my odinary phone only. it's better formatted now. It's always better to format the code so as you can get better help. anyways now it's formatted. hope you will get some answers, cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I suggest you to read about  1. overriding , 2. overloading, 3. Polymorphism of method calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.f( calls the method inside A because the reference type of the object is A. If you want to call the method of C with an A object, you have to declare it in this way:

```
A a = new C();
a.f(0);
```

Pay attention: you can call in this way only the overridden methods of A inside C, so the method f() of C should have the same signature of the method of A. In your case the signature is different because of the input type (long instead of a double). Like this:

```
class A {
    void f(double x ) { 
        System.out.print ("A.f(double=" + x + ") "); 
    }
}
class C extends A {
    void f(double q ) {
        System.out.print ("C.f(long=" + q + ") ");
    }
}
public class PolySur {
    public static void main (String args [ ]) {
        double x = 0;
        A a = new C();
        a.f(x);
    }
}
```